# Convert comma separated array to nested array with php function

Tags: php

I need to convert array_1 to array_2 with a PHP function. I tried many things but nothing works. I hope someone can help me out here. I think I need an each function or something to loop through the comma separated array and convert it into the array_2.

```
$array_1 = array (
  0 => '6801,6800,7310,6795',
);

$array_2 = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => '6801',
    1 => '6800',
    2 => '7310',
    3 => '6795',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution

```php
<?php

$array_1 = array (
  0 => '6801,6800,7310,6795',
);


$array_2 = array();

foreach ($array_1 as $value) {

    array_push($array_2 , explode(",",$value)); 
}
               

print_r($array_2);

?>
```

The output that i got

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 6801 [1] => 6800 [2] => 7310 [3] => 6795 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer, but do you also know how to get rid of the first array? See this questions too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813885/update-post-meta-with-array-without-being-nested

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP explode function. https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

```php
$newArray[] = explode(",", $array_1[0]);

// output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6801
            [1] => 6800
            [2] => 7310
            [3] => 6795
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array with a value returned by the explode function. Reset always returns the first value of the array regardless of the key.

```
$array_1 = array (0 => '6801,6800,7310,6795');

$newArray = [explode(",", reset($array_1))];
```